# Drupal in subdirectory behind reverse proxy

Tags: php, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, drupal

On my public-facing host, Apache works as reverse proxy to a non-public host, where a Drupal 9 instance is symlinked under the web root. Drupal answers to requests, but it outputs any local links with the symlink name included. Apparently because the PHP request variable `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` includes it.

How do I tell Drupal about it's "actual" base path?

#### The details

Public host config:

```
<Location "/">
  ProxyPreserveHost on
  ProxyPassReverse "https://otherserver/webb/"
</Location>
```

On `otherserver`, my domain `example.com` is a virtual host with its root in `/var/www/sites/example.com/html`. There is this symlink `webb`, pointing to the Drupal location:

```
/var/www/sites/example.com/html/webb -> /var/www/sites/example.com/html/drupal8/web/
```

Drupal responds, but in the response HTML, a link that should be to `/about` is instead to `/webb/about`, and the same goes for assets, etc.

If I echo `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`, I get `/webb/index.php`.

Comment: This may [be a better fit at the Drupal SE](https://drupal.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by altering `REQUEST_URI` and `SCRIPT_NAME` in `settings.php`:

```php
$trim_path = '/webb';
if (isset($GLOBALS['request'])) {
  $request = $GLOBALS['request'];
  if ($request->server->get('SCRIPT_NAME') == "$trim_path/index.php") {
    $request->server->set('SCRIPT_NAME', '/index.php');
    $request_uri = substr($request->server->get('REQUEST_URI'), strlen($trim_path));
    $request->server->set('REQUEST_URI', $request_uri);
  }
}
```

Kudos to lightsurge for the earliest [mention of this idea](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2528988#comment-10527558) that I could find.